# Server excution failed error

Tags: networking, windows-10

I suffer from this problem since updating to windows 1o. It Happens after every new start when I paly music files with windows media player. At the same time the network and homegroup done t work. The only solution is to reboot.

Answer (score 0):

This happens a lot to me. When this happens, do NOT close Windows Media Player, but instead re-open the file you were trying to open.

To avoid this, you can also open Windows Media Player first and then open the file you are trying to play.

**If the above doesn't work:**
You can try resetting Windows Media Player, which should hopefully get rid of this problem,

1. Open the Run command and type the following without quotes. This will reset Windows Media Player.

   ```
       "msdt.exe -id WindowsMediaPlayerConfigurationDiagnostic"
   ```
2. If Step 1 didn't work, you can also reset WMP following these instructions: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-pictures/how-to-reset-windows-media-player-to-default/60c1903d-7bde-465a-8361-2e522ed742f1

Comment: Media player doesn t open at all, I just see the failure message!!!

Comment: Kudzu to trying to understand that post. I can only guess at the question.